# Is $ e^{e^q + q} $ a transcendental number for every rational number q?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Is $ e^{e^q + q} $ a transcendental number for every rational number q?

This question was also asked here: https://www.wetenschapsforum.nl/viewtopic.php?t=213111&start=30

***Some extra background:*** I was wondering whether the following definitions lead to a mathematically interesting family of function classes.

(i) Let the function class $ \mathbb{D}^0 $ be the set of all continuous functions f from $ \mathbb{Q} $ to $ \mathbb{R} $ for which f(x) is transcendental for all rational x.

(ii) Let the function class $ \mathbb{D}^n $ for positive natural numbers n be the set of all continuous functions f from $ \mathbb{Q} $ to $ \mathbb{R} $ for which the n-th derivative of f exists and is an element of $ \mathbb{D}^0 $.

Now on another website (Wetenschapsforum.nl) somebody suggested $ f: \mathbb{Q} \to \ \mathbb{R} ; f(x) = e^{e^x} $ as a member of $ \mathbb{D}^1 $. And that suggestion lead to the question of this topic.

Comment: I doubt that we can decide this question with the current knowledge about transcendental numbers. If $q$ is non-zero rational, $e^q+q$ is transcendental, so the character of the given number is unclear.

Answer (score 7):

**Assuming [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture)**:

The case $q=0$ is trivial, so assume $q \ne 0$, so $q$ and $e^q$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$, so the conjecture says that $\Bbb Q(q, e^q, e^q, e^{e^q})$ has transcendence degree at least $2$.

But the field $\Bbb Q(q, e^q, e^q, e^{e^q})$ is the same as the field $\Bbb Q(e^q, e^{e^q+q})$, so $e^{e^q+q}$ must be transcendental.

Comment: So is it save to say that it's highly unlikely that the transcendence of $ e^{e^q + q} $ for all rational q can be proved with the methods that are currently known?

Comment: Yeah. We don't even know if $e^e$ is rational. There's a lot about transcendental numbers that we don't know.